# Merge trees haskell

Tags: haskell, merge, tree

I have got something like this

```
data Tree a = Null |Nod (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

What I want to do is create a function merge that will merge two given trees and the root of the final tree will be always the root of the left leaf of the first tree.
The purpose is to remove the left leaf while doing so.

Comment: the problem is ill-specified. there are many trees whose root is the left leaf of the first tree. which one is wanted? and what if the left tree is null or a leaf? then what is the final tree?

Comment: thanks for the answer any would do but already solve it, was making a dumb mistake

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
mergeTrees Null t2 = t2
mergeTrees (Nod left value right) t2 = Nod (mergeTrees left t2) value right
```